# Possible to redefine a breeze-generated observable as a computed field?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm probably not explaining this well...

I'm using breeze js to materialise an entity and that entity contains nearly 100 float fields.  These are calculation result fields where there are 4 individual parts and then a total and this is repeated 19 times.  So 19 x 5 = 95 fields, hence "nearly 100".

It's basically:

```
calculationResult1_materials 
calculationResult1_processes 
calculationResult1_packaging 
calculationResult1_transport 
calculationResult1_total 

calculationResult2_materials 
calculationResult2_processes 
calculationResult2_packaging 
calculationResult2_transport 
calculationResult2_total 

calculationResult3_materials 
etc...
```

As would seem obvious, the "total" field contains the sum of the other 4 parts but is also stored as there is a legacy system that accesses just that field and this prevents the sum having to be done every time someone wants to see the total.

As breeze materialises the total fields as a plain observable just like the other fields, it means that every time I recalculate any one of the 4 other fields for any of the calculations, I have to manually re-sum the 4 individual constituent parts (materials, packaging, processes, transport) and put the result into the "total" observable which is bound to the div in my html page that displays it.

Whereas this works, it strikes me that this may not be the most efficient way of doing things. Obviously I could independently create 19 computedObservables in my viewmodel that contain the 4 other fields for each calculation and then bind to that instead of each actual "total" observable, but that would mean updating the code manually if a field name changed for example.

Is there any way of redefining the observable as a computedobservable in some way such that it would automatically calculate whenever any of the 4 other parts of the calculation changed and still be part of the entity so that breeze saved the changes afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like "model.js" in your app where you define how Breeze handles data. You should expose function `configureMetadataStore` and there you should place function:

```
function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore){
  metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('MyContainerClassFromServerModel', null, thisClassInitializer);
```

After that, you need to define `thisClassInitializer` where you tell Breeze what to do with, as you call it, "materialized object":

```
function thisClassInitializer(myObject){
  myObject.customTotal = ko.computed({
    read: function(){
      return myObject.materials() + myObject.processes() + myObject.packaging() + myObject.transport();
    },
    write: function(newValue){
      myObject.total(newValue);
    }
  });
}
```

This should do the trick. Or what just came to my mind, you can define it like:

```
function thisClassInitializer(myObject){
  myObject.customTotal = ko.computed({
    var newValue = myObject.materials() + myObject.processes() + myObject.packaging() + myObject.transport();
    myObject.total(newValue);
    return newValue;
  });
}
```

The difference is that for the first one I can't guarantee without trying it (not that skilled with this ko binding), but for the other one I'm quite sure it should work.

Explanation:
When you define something like this, whenever Breeze "materializes" an object from server into an observable object, it will call initializer as well. This way you can modify what fields your object has - usually you put computed values in there (like total) so you don't need to save it on the server as well. Ideally, you don't need "total" on server because it holds no additional information - all the information is in other variables and this value can be calculated.

Comment: Thanks. As I pointed out in the OP, I have to have the total on there for a legacy app that has limited capabilities.  What stops the initialiser being called on every field though...?  Bear in mind there are 4 lots of 19 individual fields (76 in total) and then 1 lot of 19 fields for the totals of each individual calculation. It's not ONE total for the whole table.  Won't the initialiser method you've shown create a "customTotal" property on every single field I materialise?

Comment: You can create customTotal for each group of fields:
`customTotal1 = ko.computed({ var value = myObject.materials1() + ... });`
It is ugly, but legacy code is ugly so... :)

Comment: Ah, so the initializer method you show is called just once for each entity, so when I read/create new for that entity, it gets called once and I set up my computedobservables in there?  However... isn't this just creating a whole new set of 19 "customTotal" observables so I'll have 5 lots of 19 observables (including one set of 19 being the total field held on file) then another set of 19 computed observables?  This is not redefining the total field then and I'd still need to manually put that result into the database field prior to saving?

Comment: True, you would have that many more observables, but this ones are computed and not saved into the database - it's computed when data is loaded and/or changed while also syncing with total that is saved in the database. Also, being computed, you don't need to check if any of those observables making each total changes, computed would be called automatically.

Comment: But how is the created computedObservable "synced" with the total stored in the database?  I'd still need to do that manually during the saveChanges method, wouldn't I?  Nothing in the initializer method creates a link between the computedObservable and each plain observable total field, does it?

Comment: both solutions have `myObject.total(newValue);` when computed total changes which as you can see changes your original total value.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Completely missed that!

Comment: Having said that. This assumes one total, so I'd need to do 19 of these in the initializer, correct?

Comment: Correct. But on the other hand, you only write them on one place, at initialization and never ever have to think about updating them manually.

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT use a KO computed!

Instead, in the custom initializer, I would subscribe to the Breeze `EntityAspect.propertyChanged` event with a recalculation function added to the EntityType's prototype).

This will be far lighter weight (one method instead of 1000s), more performant, and easier to maintain once you figure out the pattern for updating totals based on the name of the property that changed.

The code would look something like this:

```
function calculationResultCtor() {/*... stuff in the ctor */ }

calculationResultCtor.recalcTotals(propertyName, newValue)
    /* do whatever based on the newValue and the propertyName 
       remember to use the parens required by KO observables
    */
}

function calculationResultInitializer(cr) {
   // listen for any property change in this calculationResult instance
   cr.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function(args){
        var propName = args.propertyName;
        if (/_total/.test(propName)) return; // skip changes to total properties
        args.entity.recalcTotals(propName, args.newValue);
   });
}

metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('CalculationResult', 
    calculationResultCtor, calculationResultInitializer);
```

I can think of even more clever ways (e.g., a dictionary of calculation fns, keyed by `propertyName`) to make this more efficient but you see where I'm going.

The one thing I'd worry about (and if it's an issue it will be an issue for with your KO computed approach too) is what I call "propertyChanged" storms where some automated process is updating a lot of properties at once.

The solution for that - if it is a problem and I'm not saying that it is - would be to latch the recalc event so that it terminates during the storm and then, when it's over, you just recalc every total in a single pass through the entity.

The important point is where I started: do NOT create 1000s of KO computeds! And yes there will be 1000s because your plan would add at least 19 computeds per entity so a mere 53 entity instances puts you over 1000. That is not good.

Comment: Thanks Ward.  Oddly enough (for me!) I'm already doing a subscription to the entityaspect.propertychanged event for exactly this reason. As soon as I pick up the entity I extend it to look out for changes on key fields and this triggers the calculation. However... this does mean I'm pretty much back where I started then.  It seems as though I'm doing roughly the right thing and all I need to do is finish the calcs, total it up and then put the result into the database "total" field for that particular calculation.  I'm happy enough doing it that way, just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: This was the best I could come up with. Glad you're not thinking of adding a zillion KO observables :-)

Comment: If I was clever enough I'd try to think of a way of suggesting an enhancement to the breeze entity creation procedure whereby it was possible to redefine a physical database field as a computed observable instead of creating new extraneous ones!  I don't understand enough about how the system works to even know if that's a good idea or not. In my mind it would be a case of using an initializer function as suggested above to redefine a field as a computed and make it the result of a function like `entity.fieldName.redefine = function() {ko.computed(entity.otherfield1 + entity.otherfield2)}`

Comment: Again please please please don't do that. You do not want to litter your entities with computeds and certainly not in profuse numbers as your use case suggests. We certainly would NOT want to generate them. What a disaster that would be.  Good luck. W

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not the place, but I'd like to know why you so strongly advise against using ko.computed variables. For instance, I use in my application ko.computed variables for easier transformation between date formats (computed reads from model, computed is bound to view input date) and similar transformations. If you do it for that purpose, I can't see a big downside. I don't have anything against your suggestion, just trying to find out different methods and possible optimization and learn - after all, I am using Breeze for just couple of months.

Comment: @Ward You rock!! I had to say thank you for saving my day.. Brilliant answer